# Conversation functionality in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to add conversation functionality in my application. How can I do this? Is there any gem that help me?

See image, I want like this

[image]

Functionality look like -> see https://www.etsy.com/conversations

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a gem for this, but you can archive that behavior with [socket.io](http://socket.io/)

Its really easy to connect clients to a socket.io server and to stream the chat (and even to create a private chat on the public rooms).

For the socket server, you can deploy it to [heroku](http://www.heroku.com) and [nodejitsu](http://nodejitsu.com/), last day I created a custom chat system (it wasn't really a chat but a way to see who's online and to create notifications between the user online) and just take me a few hours.